SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers
I have the next gradle configuration:
configurations {
    all {
        // Exclude Spring's default logging framework
        exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
        exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module : 'logback-access'
        // exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module : 'logback-classic'
    }
}

and also I have the next dependency:
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic
    testImplementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.6'

Because I need some of the utilities, such as
private ListAppender<ILoggingEvent> listAppender = new ListAppender<>();

For that regard I need to import:
import ch.qos.logback.core.read.ListAppender;
import io.athena.th.adapter.JwtPX.SessionData;

to do something like this
Logger fooLogger = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandleExceptionUtil.class);
// create and start a ListAppender
listAppender.start();
// add the appender to the logger
fooLogger.addAppender(listAppender);
As you can see I have commented:
// exclude group: 'ch.qos.logback', module : 'logback-classic'

and I am getting an error:
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J providers.
SLF4J: Found provider [ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider@6c49ea0c]
SLF4J: Found provider [org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider@417bfebd]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.

But if I uncomment this exclusion I will not have the ch.qos.logback functionalities.
Any advice o how can I solve this?
Thanks!

It's difficult to answer the question until there is the whole dependencies {} block posted. If you take a fresh Spring Boot project, the logback-core should be automatically present in both (implementation and testImplementation), because it transitively comes from spring-boot-starter-logging, which in turn comes from spring-boot-starter. Normally, you should not exclude anything if you use Spring Boot and want Logback as a logging implementation, everything comes you transitively.

But if I don't exclude anything I got the issues I mentioned above

If you want to keep Logback, you should find which dependency includes org.apache.logging.slf4j.SLF4JServiceProvider. It might turns out that you have to exclude a single dependency only.
If not, you can always set the system property slf4j.provider in order to choose the logging framework implementation you prefer, e. g. slf4j.provider=ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.LogbackServiceProvider
